# Watch a folder when adding files and write the filename into some file

Tags: node.js, webpack

Running a Webpack+Vue project. I need to watch the `src` folder for new files, and append the file names into `.eslintrc`, so ESLint will lint the new files in real time. (Because it's an old large project, I excluded all src files and just want to lint those newly added.)